# connect android device with printer and print document

Tags: android, sockets, printing, android-wifi

I am developing an app in which I want to integrate print feature.Is it possible to send file to printer(for any company or brand) from app and print it.

so far googled and found following code but no luck.

```
try {

        client = new Socket(ipAddress, port);

        // create a byte array to file
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        // read the file
        bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

        outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
        // write file to the output stream byte by byte
        outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        outputStream.flush();
        bufferedInputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        client.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note: I do not want to use Google Cloud Print. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Me too looking solution for this issue, do you have any solution right now?. If you have, please share with me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use lpdspooler http://lpdspooler.sourceforge.net/,  that is, if the printer supports LPR/LPD. If you can give some more details about the environment (printer, etc).

Comment: thanx for ans. I want to print for any arbitrary printer. printer may be of any company, any brand.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly connect to a printer and print from Android, unless the printer is cloud enabled.

However, you can add the printer to your Google Cloud Print account and print to it using the APIs available.

Note though that the computer that the printer is attached to will need to be in for print jobs to be processed.

Comment: Is it not possible without cloud and computer ? If not then how `printershar` and `canon-photo print` works ?

Comment: I don't know about printershar but for the canon-phone print, it works by the android app having an app installed by Canon which works the functionality of their printers. i.e. as their website says it will only work on PIXMA and SELPHY compact photo printers.